# Is sql use multiple column indexes?(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         INT NOT NULL,
    last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
);

1. SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name='bob' and first_name='John';

2. SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name='John' and last_name='bob';
```

The first sql must use index, however is the second use the index? and why?

Comment: It's a mistake to think where conditions are always evaluated left to right..

Comment: A side issue:  Use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR` (unless all names are expected to be exactly 30 chars long).

Answer (score 1):

Both can use the index, if the optimizer "feels" like it. It might, for whatever reason chose not to, but the order of the `AND` operands shouldn't be such a reason -- in fact I'd considered that a bug if it was.

Since `AND` commutes, there's no difference if the condition on `first_name` comes first or second in the `AND` operation (and analog for `last_name`).

You can try it yourself. Just compare the plans. Most likely they are identical.

And remember, SQL is a descriptive language. You don't tell the system what to do, but what you want. It'll figure out itself how it gets that and how this is done in a fast way. So it's free to rework the queries and will do so especially with such trivialities as changing the order of operands when possible.

Comment: However, that index would be useless if the condition only tested for `first_name`:  `WHERE first_name = 'sticky'` without also testing `last_name`.  That is, the order in the `WHERE` does not matter, but the order in the `INDEX` does.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql